# choosing the best structure of the random effects in a GLMM

Tags: glm, lmer, random-effects

I am trying to choose the best random effect structure in a GLMM, before starting with the fixed terms. To do that I include all the fixed effect and their interactions (beyond optimal model) and then I try with different combinations of the random factors. I am using the formula lmer(). Models were estimated with REML. Then I get the AIC() of each model and I compare them.

But I want to know also the AIC of the model without random effects. I read that then I should use gls(). But I could use also glm(). And the AIC of the same model with gls, and the same model with glm, are very different.

Is this the best method to choose the best random effect structure in a GLMM? Could I compare the AIC values gotten with a lmer() with other AIC values gotten with gls or glm??

Thanks and best regards!

Comment: this might be better for [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com).  Can you show us a [reproducible example](http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000) ?

Answer (score 0):

I have also been looking for a good solution to test alternative random effect structures for GLMMs. There is some great [discussion on the topic here.](http://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_I_optimize_the_random_effect_structure_in_a_GLMM) The best general overview of the challenges is [summarized pretty well here](http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq#reml-glmm). But for the most part allot of the solutions seem to be under development or are just too far out there for most reviewers, co-authors & other readers to understand. The problem is that as the complexity of the random effect component is increased AIC scores will generally be lower, but these models might still be over-fitting the data. I would tend to set up the random effect structure according to the experimental design, practicality and intuition.

I tested alternative random effect structures for a GLMM by randomly splitting the original data [into training and testing sets](http://www.gettinggeneticsdone.com/2011/02/split-data-frame-into-testing-and.html) and then comparing AUC scores across the competing models. I am not sure if this is the perfect solution, but it seemed to work well for me.

[image]

Not sure if this will work or if it is even an appropriate solution. But, when comparing AIC scores, the model in red with the nested random effects seemed to be the best. Here through cross validation we can see that the single random effect of PlotID alone (green) is just as good as the competing model with the more complex random effect structure.

its possible to see here that the model with one random intercept of PlotID was just as good as the model

Answer (score 0):

When choosing a random effect oyu may want to keep it maximal and in line with your design. See this link for more info : https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3881361/